# Conditional Pop-up Box within a for loop (Sheets)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got the code below working, but when I try to add a Browser.msgBox() once there is a duplicate in the comparison, the code keeps running until it exceeds its time limit.

The idea is to notify the user that the item he/she is trying to add is duplicated and have the script stop running.

```
var duplicate = false;
  for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
      for(var j = 0; j < dataArquivoItens.length; j++){
        if(data[x].join() == dataArquivoItens[j].join()){
        duplicate = true;
        break;
        }
      }
  }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check for dupes before you add data.  If you find any report them all at once outside of any loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are only breaking out from the `if` statement, this is why your code keeps iterating

If you want to break from all nested loops/ statements - give them a name

Sample:

```
var duplicate = false;
loop1:
  for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
      loop2:
      for(var j = 0; j < dataArquivoItens.length; j++){
        if(data[x].join() == dataArquivoItens[j].join()){
        duplicate = true;
        Browser.msgBox("That's a duplicate");
        break loop1;
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Hi! How about adding a pop up message to this piece of code once duplicate = true?

Comment: For this you can use e.g. [msgBox](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#msgboxprompt) - see my updated answer!

Comment: That sounds so obvious, but once I add that, just like I had tried before, I got running function status forever. Nothing pops up when I try debugging it.

Comment: The pop-up will appear in the sheet, not in the Apps Script editor. The code stopps running once the user clicks it away.

Comment: I get it. It doesn't pop up in the sheet.

Comment: It sounds then like the condition `data[x].join() == dataArquivoItens[j].join()` is never fulfilled. You can troubleshoot implementing logs. Otherwise, can you provide a test sheet that exhibits this issue and a complete code including the definition of `data` and `dataArquivoItens`?

Comment: There it is:
The sheet EditarItem is the whose data if not equal to what's on ArquivoItens, then have a popup box asking the user to confirm the addition of that item.:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qhd92begwwy9PA5FmF5kENQydQou18BKhPiULhfvRS4/edit?usp=sharing
I even tried escaping spaces within the boxes' string contents, but it keeps running forever. Thanks a million!

Comment: I just tested it with your sheet and it worked correctly. Obviously, once you obtain a message box, the code continues running forever until you manually click on "OK". If this is not what you desire, you can use [toast()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg) instead: `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("That's a duplicate");`

Comment: This might something wrong with my browser, then. Thanks for checking!